# I want to write a google sheets program that will send an email when I get within a certain date range of today

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet with birthdays and I want to be notified through email 3 days prior to the birthday that it is upcoming for that person. So far I have written this

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
function checkBirthday() {

  var Avals = ss.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
  var today = new Date();
  for (var i = 2; i<Alast; i++) {
    //does not function as expected
    if (DateDif(today, sheet.getRange(i, 2)) == 3) {
      var subject = sheet.getRange(i,1) + "'s Birthday";
      var message = sheet.getRange(i,1) + "'s birthday is coming up in 3 days on " + sheet.getRange(i,2);
        MailApp.sendEmail("email1", subject, message);

    }
  }  
}
```

I realize there is no `datedif` function it is simply pseudocode for what I wish to accomplish. I am new to this so am I simply missing a function that would accomplish that? Or is it something more complex?

Comment: Make the cell containing the date a `Date()` like this `var date = new Date(cell)` . After that just compare `today.getDate()` with `date.getDate()` . Whatever addition, subtraction is needed do it with `getDate()`

Comment: Why don't you create the events in a Google Calendar and have a 3 day reminder setting set?

Answer (score 0):

I second the using Gcal for this, but an alternative approach is to move most of your text handling and calculations to sheets. I recommend this approach as it let's you change the messaging and settings much easier than editing your code each time.

Sample Spreadsheet - 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uICgapzf-8Svw_epEQcNqOwYyXWfzux2yHltFaegtBc/edit?usp=sharing

From there you just have your app script look at column G and if it is TRUE send email. Set cron tasks for each day and you are good to go.

If you want to ALSO send text sms to yourself or the birthday person you can check out my tutorial for [connecting sheets with twilio](https://nathanielkam.com/send-mass-personalized-sms-using-twilio-and-google-sheets/)